# use ternary operator as if elseif and else

Tags: laravel, if-statement, conditional-operator

I want to check **if** the role is agency then the output is `$agencyUsers` **else if** the role is officer then the output is `$officeUsers` **else** I need to output **'No Group'**

I try this but the output is **'No Group'** for all users

```
<td>{{ strtolower($user->getRoleNames()) === 'agency' ? $agencyUsers : strtolower($user->getRoleNames()) === 'officer' ? $officeUsers : 'No Group'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the second ternary in parentheses, this should work:

```
strtolower($user->getRoleNames()) === 'agency' ? $agencyUsers : (strtolower($user->getRoleNames()) === 'officer' ? $officeUsers : 'No Group')
```

However, I recommend using a different approach.  Blade allows for if conditions, which may be more readable than multiple ternaries, or even extracting this logic to a view function.